# get the value of the dropdown of the particular row in a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my html code

```
<td style="display:none">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="form-control" id="riexclusion">
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
```

i want to get the selected value from the dropdown list of every row.

I tried this jquery to retrieve the value..

```
var selectedstatus = $('#riexclusion option:selected').text();
alert(selectedstatus);
var totalrow = $("#ritable > tbody > tr").length;
for (var i = 0; i <= totalrow; i++) {
    exclusion = $('tbody#riDecisionvalues tr:eq(' + i + ')td:eq(8)').select();
}
```

help me with this...

add [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g466pusg/)

Comment: Do you have duplicate Identifiers (Ids)?

Comment: do you want to have list of selected values from each row?

Comment: But the id of the drop down list here is not unique for each row...

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: I need each vlaues separately when i exceute the loop

Comment: @AarthiRavendiran, please check the answer provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to remove duplicate `id`s instead you can use `class` as shown below -

```
<td style="display:none">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="form-control" class="riexclusion">
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
```

Use below jQuery to get each selected value from dropdown

```
//iterate all select under each tr
$("#ritable  tbody  tr").find(".riexclusion").each(function(){
   selectedVal = $(this).val();
   alert(selectedVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Id of an element must be unique, so use as a `riexclusion` class(`<select class="form-control riexclusion">`), then you can use [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/) to get an array of all the selected values

```
var exclusions = $('.riexclusion').map(function () {
    return this.value
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/054tyvqo/)

```
$('#riexclusion').on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$("#ritable tbody tr:nth-child(8)")..find('select').val();
```

or if you want to loop through

```
var selectedstatus = $('#riexclusion').val();
$('tbody#riDecisionvalues tr').each(function(){
    $(this).find('td').eq(8).find('select').val(selectedstatus)
})
```